# Guzzle Cache subscriber

Tags: caching, guzzle

I'm trying to set up caching with guzzle but can't seem to get it to work and haven't found any documentation on it. I'm using guzzle 5 and the description service to make calls to a web api. The cache subscriber seems to be attached to the client but no caching seems to take place on my queries when my web page is reloaded.

Here is my ClientFactory class i use to build the client :

```
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\FilesystemCache;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Cache\CachePlugin;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Command\Guzzle\Description;
use GuzzleHttp\Command\Guzzle\GuzzleClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Cache\CacheStorage;
use GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Cache\CacheSubscriber;

class ClientFactory
{
    public static function factory(array $config = [])
    {
    $defaultConfig = [
        'defaults' => [
            'headers' => ['User-Agent' => 'MyWebApi/1.0.0 +https://mywebsite.com'],
            'auth' => 'oauth'
        ],
    ];



    $client = new Client(self::mergeRecursive($defaultConfig, $config));
    $client->setDefaultOption('verify', false);

    $array = CacheSubscriber::attach($client, [ "storage" =>  new CacheStorage(new FilesystemCache("cache/"))]);
    $service = include __DIR__ . '/../../resources/service.php';
    $description = new Description($service);

    return new GuzzleClient($client, $description);
}

public static function &mergeRecursive(array &$array1, &$array2 = null)
{
    $merged = $array1;

    if (is_array($array2)) {
        foreach ($array2 as $key => $val) {
            if (is_array($array2[$key])) {
                $merged[$key] = is_array($merged[$key]) ? self::mergeRecursive($merged[$key], $array2[$key]) : $array2[$key];
            } else {
                $merged[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    return $merged;
}
}
```

Thanks for any answer that may help

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you're in the same boat, but are you using master branch?

I was setting up the Cache Subscriber myself and found that the cached responses would always turn invalid because the default ttl value was not set.

I found this was an issue because I was using version 0.1.0 but it seemed to be corrected on master (https://github.com/guzzle/cache-subscriber/blob/master/src/CacheStorage.php#L48) where you can set a default ttl.

Comment: Thanks for the answer will check this out and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Guzzle 5, use this cache subscriber https://github.com/EmanueleMinotto/guzzle-cache-subscriber which you can give different cache providers like FileSystem, Redis etc implemented in doctrine cache.